# how do I find out the speed at which an equation changes it's direction to come up with an appropriate interval for my Bisection method

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, bisection

I want to use bisection method to find all roots of an equation within a given domain. my logic is very simple , divide the given domain into sub domains such that for any given sub-domain only one root exists at most. check if f(a)*f(b)<0 if no then skip to next interval else find root(bisection). my problem however how do I decide the appropriate sub domain size? for a stable function that doesn't change direction often having a small interval would be a waste of time wheres for a fast "unstable" function using a big interval might risk having more than one root in an interval.

is there anyway that using the first two derivatives that I can tell me about the behavior of a function to come up with an appropriate interval accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

If you can tell upper/lower bounds on the derivative in a given interval, then you can predict the largest/smallest value that the function might take in that interval and see if it is able to cross zero.

Comment: that's exactly what I was thinking, my assumption is that between each consecutive minima and maxima there exists at most one root, so running a bisection algorithm within this interval if it pass the f(a)*f(b)<0 test will guarantee to return the root and eventually all roots. However, the problem that I was facing, is how to find the upper and lower bounds becasue eventually these are also the roots of the first derivative of f(x) which brings us back to the original problem, what's an appropriate interval to find all roots of first derivative?

Comment: I never said that you need to find the roots of the derivative. I spoke about bounding the derivative.